# custom threshold for charging laptop battery

Tags: battery-life

In order to avoid unnecessary recharge cycles on Ubuntu, is there a way to set the threshold determining when the laptop battery is being charged? Perhaps a manual switch to disable charging altogether?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, plug it in when you want to charge it and unplug it when you don't want to.

Comment: Funny. What if I have a battery at 50% whose charge I wanna use up to go wireless, without shutting down the laptop or initiating a recharge cycle before unplugging (quite a frequent scenario for me)?

Comment: Is there any way you can clarify your comment? You don't have to shut down to unplug it.

Comment: If I unplug after inserting the semi-charged battery, it will start charging. If I unplug before inserting a battery, the laptop will shut down hard.
I've found this, but it's for ThinkPads only: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Battery_charge_control_features

Answer (score 3):

For IBM Thinkpads there exist a module tp_smapi to control charge thresholds. It you fix the start charge threshold at 60% and stop at 95%, the battery will charge upto 95% and stop charging (It will not discharge either). Once the AC power goes off the laptop will discharge but will not start recharging, even if plugged into AC, till the battery has discharged below 60%. Its useful feature to increase battery life as Li-ion batteries are best stored at 40%. If you don't often go off AC power the battery will remain at 40-60% as per threshold set by you and hence last for a long time. I'm not aware if the same module would work for other laptops as well. Sam - IBM Thinkpad - R52/R60.